# In DRF how do I serialize a related model(OneToOne) and display the data not in a list data type but single value instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

The code is given below with the present output and expected output.
In the `ProductPriceMapping` table the `ProductDetail` table and PriceList are related with a `OneToOne` relation, but When the data for Price is fetched with the `related_name` argument there must be one value for one product, the data is being displayed is a `list` data type.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class PriceList(models.Model):
    priceCode = models.BigAutoField(primary_key= True)
    maxRetailPrice= models.FloatField(max_length=20)
    baseDiscount = models.FloatField(max_length=20, default=0)
    seasonalDiscount = models.FloatField(max_length=20, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.maxRetailPrice)

class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    productCode = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productName

class ProductPriceMapping(models.Model):
    productPriceCode= models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    productCode= models.ForeignKey(ProductDetail,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='price')
    priceCode= models.OneToOneField(PriceList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.priceCode)
```

serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import CategoryDetail, EmployeeDetail, ProductCategoryMapping, ProductPriceMapping, SalaryDetail, ProductDetail, PriceList

class ProductPriceListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PriceList
        fields = ('priceCode','maxRetailPrice',
                  'baseDiscount', 'seasonalDiscount')

class ProductPriceMappingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= ProductPriceMapping
        fields= ('productPriceCode','productCode', 'priceCode')

class ProductDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category= serializers.StringRelatedField(many= True, read_only= True)
    price = serializers.StringRelatedField( many= True, read_only= True)
    class Meta:
        model = ProductDetail
        fields = ('productCode', 'productName', 'manufacturer','category', 'price')
```

The result of API as it looks:

```
[
    {
        "productCode": 1,
        "productName": "NeoChef",
        "manufacturer": "LG",
        "category": [
            "1: Microwave Oven"
        ],
        "price": [
            "26000.0"  ##expected the price value not be in a list
        ]
    },
    {
        "productCode": 2,
        "productName": "The Frame",
        "manufacturer": "Samsung",
        "category": [
            "2: Television"
        ],
        "price": [
            "120000.0" ##expected the price value not be in a list
        ]
    },
    {
        "productCode": 3,
        "productName": "Galaxy S22+",
        "manufacturer": "Samsung",
        "category": [
            "3: Smart Phone"
        ],
        "price": [
            "79000.0" ##expected the price value not be in a list
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected result:

````
[
    {
        "productCode": 1,
        "productName": "NeoChef",
        "manufacturer": "LG",
        "category": [
            "1: Microwave Oven"
        ],
        "price": "26000.0"  
    }
]```
````

Comment: The ProductPriceMapping to ProductDetail relationship is a ForeignKey meaning that there can be many related objects returned by "price", it's not a OneToOne relation

Comment: when used OneToOne relation to ProductDetail, there is a traceback saying "'ProductPriceMapping' object is not iterable"

Comment: @Roham which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, I solved in this way:

**models.py**

```py
class ProductPriceMapping(models.Model):
    productPriceCode= models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    productCode= models.OneToOneField(ProductDetail,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='price')
    priceCode= models.ForeignKey(PriceList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.priceCode)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class ProductDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category= serializers.StringRelatedField(many= True, read_only= True)
    price = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only= True)
    class Meta:
        model = ProductDetail
        fields = ('productCode', 'productName', 'manufacturer','category', 'price')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `price` field is not a one-to-one related field, you either need to change the `productCode` to `OneToOneField` or if you don't want to change the DB field, you can achieve the same result simply with `SerializerMethodField`. In the first case, removing `many=True` argument from the serializer field should help. In second case, `SerializerMethodField` will help you to make your custom representation, e.g.:

```
class ProductDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category= serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ProductDetail
        fields = ('productCode', 'productName', 'manufacturer','category', 'price')

    def get_price(self, obj):
        # If it's guaranteed that there will be only one related object, or retrieve the needed object depending on your demands
        return str(obj.price.first())
```

Comment: Already tried that, but then it looks like
"price": app.ProductPriceMapping.None

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use `MethodField`...

```
class ProductPriceMappingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    priceCode = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model= ProductPriceMapping
        fields= ('productPriceCode','productCode', 'priceCode')
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_priceCode(obj):
        return obj.priceCode.maxRetailPrice  # or any other fields that you like to show in your response
```

but if you want to show all of the priceList fields based on your other serializer you can do something like:

```
class ProductPriceMappingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    priceCode = ProductPriceListSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model= ProductPriceMapping
        fields= ('productPriceCode','productCode', 'priceCode')
```